# How to debug `$Failed` messages

Tags: debugging

The following quits with message `$Failed` and no other information on Mathematica 13.2 (also on [cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/5ddf660c-3ee0-4122-8831-72c9170e1a2e)), are there any debugging tricks to find the source of the error?

```
d = 10;
R2toSpectrum[R_, d_] := Module[{h, dd, decay},
   decay = 
    If[R < 1.001, 100., 
     dd /. FindRoot[
       HarmonicNumber[d, dd]^2/HarmonicNumber[d, 2 dd] == R, {dd, 2, 
        0, 100}]];
   h = Table[i^-decay, {i, 1, d}];
   h/Total[h]
   ];
rrPlot2[R_] := Plot[Max[R2toSpectrum[R, d]], {R, 1, d}]
rrPlot2[5]
```

Comment: `rrPlot2[5]` returns `$Failed`, so looking at the definition for `rrPlot2[R_]`, we replace the instances of `R` with 5, and see what happens.  `Plot[Max[R2toSpectrum[5, d]], {5, 1, d}]` returns `$Failed`.  But that variable specification is weird.  Did you mean to use `rrPlot2[d_] :=` when defining the function?

Comment: Ah yes that was the problem. Wish that error message was more informative though, like " incorrect specification for plot"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow from Brett's suggestion:

`rrPlot[d_] :=  ListLinePlot[Table[{i, Max[R2toSpectrum[i, d]]}, {i, 1, d}]]`

```
rrPlot[10]
```

[image]